# Is a slow home page better than a loading bar?

Tags: user-expectation, homepage, loading

I am working on a small site which needs to load a large amount of data to show on the home page.

The page container loads fast (~1 second) but then I need to retrieve data from a database and perform calculations on it and display it in a table.

I do this via Ajax calls, but it slows the use of the page down until this completes. If you scroll, the scrolling is jumpy, etc.

Should I allow the user full access to the page after 1 second, but for the next 10 seconds the page is a big slow and laggy to use?

Or should I just display a pop-up with a loading bar and block them using the page until the page is fully ready and responsive?

Once the home page loads, the site runs really fast and all is good.

Comment: Regardless which direction you go, both are very user unfriendly. Either you frustrate people with jumping content or you test their patience and make them wait. Are there ways you can optimize your content or cut the content into bits and display them when it's needed?

Comment: I fully agree! The data is optimised as much as possible, and the user will know it is a data heavy site, and should expect some delay to get all the data.

Comment: Do you have to display/load all of this data at once (is it crunched into a single chart or somthing) or could  you break it out into multiple data sets (load first 10 posts, then second 10, etc.)?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, all of the data is needed. It is a data analysis site.

Comment: Have you considered an [interactive loading screen (that doesn't suck)](https://venturebeat.com/2014/10/05/interactive-loading-screens/view-all/)?

Comment: I hate loading screens and usually switch away to another tab. Whatever you do make sure that it keeps loading if the users switches tabs, nothing is worse to wait a minute in other tab to discover that you have to watch the load after all.

Comment: **Background AJAX-Calls do not slow down page scrolling** - no matter how long slow requests take, you should be able to outsource heavy loads to background-tasks or promises and process them in small chunks (with service-worker or promises) so the user-experience does not slow down. I know internal pages which load millions of rows and take several seconds without much impact to the UI-Thread

Comment: Since this is a UX-Question I post this as a comment: Do browser-JS Profiling. My best guess is you are doing a lot of incremental work on the DOM inserting or moving a lot of nodes, or you do a lot of blocking operations on the foreground JS-process - both are not best practice and can usually be optimized. For DOM-Elements you could create a virtual DOM and insert your nodes in a single operation once the loading is done, or similar techniques

Comment: You could add a splash screen with a dual purpose. Eg: make a modal overlay that says "the data you are about to see if confidential, press to continue and confirm" or some such. By the time the user has been presented with the pop up, and by the time the pop up animation closes, a small delay remains by the time the data is presented. This data itself may already be partially loaded and visible.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://idlewords.com/talks/website_obesity.htm

Comment: To add on @Falco's comment, what slows down the UI is rendering after you AJAX calls return. If you want to improve interaction with the page during rendering, try to render in small chunks and add small timeouts (10-20ms) between each chunk. The total rendering time will be bigger but you won't be blocking the UI thread to much, which is what creates the laggy UX.

Comment: To add to @ThibaultD 's comment: rendering *tables* is very time-expensive as the whole table must be recalculated - using fixed width columns can mitigate this, but loading div's is much faster than adding rows to a table.

Comment: 10 seconds of lag is in the realm of unusable. I would argue you've already failed at this stage and need to go rethink your home page design and approach. None of the answers addressed the issue that you're basically blocking for 10 seconds. That's an insanely long time. The only justifiable reason is that this is an intranet application for a business, but if this is a public website for random visitors. You've lost the battle to hold their interest.

Comment: @Falco OTOH the asynchronious loading makes the page 'jumpy'. Often on such pages I find information I need only to be scrolled to another part as a large piece was just loaded above the information.

Comment: "I need to retrieve data from a database and perform calculations on it and display it in a table." Have you consider $ the result of calculation or otherwise optimize it? There should be various out-of-the-box solutions for memoization and if it's slow it's not premature optimization.

Comment: A custom loading bar for a web page is unacceptable, full stop. Now, if you have a web *application* that's so useful it *deserves* to have me sitting there waiting for a loading bar... (You'll notice that 10 seconds of delay *without* a loading bar is *also* unacceptable)

Comment: "The page container loads fast (~1 second)" Nope, taking one second isn't fast...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The latter for sure. The users will experience a poor user experience with the former.

What's interesting about this question is that it raises the notion of 'visibility of system state' or "as long as I know what's going on, I feel I am in control" and that's just what your loading bar will do.

I suppose a more important question is where this status bar is presented.
A lightbox over the page until loading finishes is one option. A bar at the head of the page is another.

Edit: Jane's solution down the page is a better way.

Edit 2: Jane's idea may have some folks not to enamoured by it "I find the way it works in Facebook incredibly stupid"

In this case, you need to go out and user test your ideas. Test a skeleton page, a page load indicator and a direct interaction and see which does best in testing. That's the real solution!

Comment: I have considered both the loading bar options, and think a lightbox over the page would be better, as it clearly blocks the page. A loading bar above the page content would still allow the user to use the page, and it may not be 100% obvious to some users that the slow page and the loading bar are connected.

Comment: I guess you could hide the content until it fully calculates? 

Also: the lightbox can be closed by the user at any time, of course, if s/he chooses

Comment: Indeed - giving them the choice: wait and watch this loading bar, or close this message, but expect a laggy page!

Comment: @Richard Don't give them a choice. The laggy page is poor UX, even if they choose it themselves. Don't give them the choice of poor UX, force the proper one.

Comment: -1 because I think neither is a good solution, I posted an answer with my suggestion.

Comment: -1: As a user I would *much* rather be in control. If the operation I want to do is a little slow, say taking 2-3 seconds for something that's normally almost instantaneous, and the item I want to manipulate takes 2-3 seconds to appear, then that delays me by ~5 seconds. The progress bar delays me by 10 seconds, always.

Comment: @Mast: I agree that laggy user experience is poor - so why would you consider adding a deliberate 10 second lag (which is what the progress bar effectively is)?

Comment: @psmears It's a wait time for a lag-free experience later.

Comment: @Mast: But that makes no sense - if the operation I want to do is small, then it's a net loss of time (and very frustrating to boot - being made to wait 10 seconds to complete a 1 second task); if what I want to do is long, then a few seconds of lag at the start will be long forgotten by the time I've finished...

Comment: @psmears As OP said, it's a data heavy page of which a user should expect it to be data heavy. So your proposed use case is explicitly thrown out the window.

Comment: @Mast: Nonsense - even on a data-heavy page, it's possible for the item I want to interact with to be at the top of the page. And indeed, with a well-designed UI, the data I want to see will always be the most visible. What's more, if the page is truly data-heavy, I may just want to look at the data (no interaction, no scrolling etc) - so showing a progress bar that blocks my view of the data slows me down for literally no gain.

Comment: ah...." say taking 2-3 seconds for something that's normally almost instantaneous, and the item I want to manipulate takes 2-3 seconds to appear, then that delays me by ~5 seconds. The progress bar delays me by 10 second" depends if you have multiple 2-3 interactions on that page. If you have many that 2-3sec lag quickly builds up vs a one off 10 second load. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @colmcq: No, because (unless the operations hugely slow down the loading), after the first few interactions, the page is fully loaded, and so it's a choice between (a) do a few interactions slower than usual, then proceed at full speed, or (b) sit doing nothing for ten seconds, then start at full speed. In case (a) I may be a little frustrated for 10s because I make slower progress towards my goal than I'd like, but in case (b) I'm much *more* frustrated, because I make *no progress at all* towards my goal--and what's more, I have 10 seconds of brain-idle time to concentrate on my frustration!

Answer (score 106):

You might want to look into **skeleton ui patterns** or **placehold patterns**. They're very popular right now and are used by for example Facebook.

I found a nice [short article](https://medium.com/anatomy-of-web-interface/placeholder-loading-ui-bbaf2222f95f) on medium that talks about it, but I'm sure you can find a lot on it around the web.
To quote the writer:

> It seems like a good alternative to the loading state since it re-enforces the content layout, hence it sets the user’s expectation of where things are right away (given that it mimics the actual content layout).

Placeholders are essentially loading bars, in the form of dummy content. It let's the user know something is coming, without causing odd jumping.

[image]

Medium itself does some very nice [progressive image loading](https://jmperezperez.com/medium-image-progressive-loading-placeholder/) that could work as an excellent placeholder as well, but you didn't give any examples of the kind of content you are looking to display.

Comment: @jane fully agree. Skeleton may even be **latest calculated data** stored in LocalStorage (with the proper formatting to show it's out of date)

Comment: [This is an article I saw in another question](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-speed-up-your-ux-with-skeleton-screens/) (forget which one though) that does a pretty good job of explaining skeleton screens.

Comment: Nice, especially if the placeholder will have the same size/position as the final content.  I don't mind slow-loading pages that much (especially if there's some indication that is IS loading), but having things jump around on the screen as the browser frantically tries to redraw to fit in each new element is really, really annoying.

Comment: Oh, that is what they are for. Whenever I see then I've think something messed up and hit reload

Comment: I find the way it works in Facebook incredibly stupid. Async content loading increases the time before content becomes available for user (the skeleton had to load before it would be able to send requests to load content that is actually interesting to the user). And error handling is poor even in Facebook: if something bad happens you end up with a skeleton page with animated placeholders that are just GIFs and not a real indication of loading progress. If FB can't make it right, I don't expect average Joe Webdeveloper to do it right either.

Comment: The screenshot looks similar to facebook... The solution smells of react, laggy and buggy.

Comment: If I were to try this approach, it'd be without its *Facebookness*. It's the slowest site I have to deal daily...

Comment: @n0rd Depends; if the skeleton is static data and thus cacheable, it may be quick enough to load to not make that much of a difference.

Comment: @Džuris The screenshot is from facebook...? It even has the facebook logo.

Comment: the more I think of this solution the more I'm beginning to go back to my original solution. With skeleton pages I'm not sure I know what's happening over and above something vaguely changing. Can I get feedback like "importing X%......importing Y% .....Import complete". See what I mean?

Comment: The question is about a 10 sec lag, so it's important to let the user know that something is happening. Typically you see this pattern with quicker load times. Just something to keep in mind as it might not have the desired effect.

Comment: I'm not sure which I hate more: the not-quite-in-time loading you propose, where I need to wait for the page to finish loading before I can do anything, or everything-at-the-start loading, where the page jumps around for a while, but at least I can start reading it.

Comment: Wow! This makes me feel ignorant. I have noticed pages doing this lately and usually hit refresh as it looks like an error to me (likely just exacerbating the problem.) I'm not sure this design is intuitive. I'd vote for *some indicator* that the page is loading besides blank placeholders.

Comment: @Wyrmwood, the horizontal bars in the post placeholders do have an animation, but it's too subtle it's very easy to miss. I agree with you it should be more obvious that something is actually loading and not broken.

Comment: I don't like this. Only reason is that am not sure if the holder is populated with all the data or not, also, it looks weird to see those empty boxes.

Answer (score 34):

Really you shouldn't put this application on your *home* page. The home page serves as the entry page to your site, and users will need quick access to navigation. I would consider even ~1s load time too long for that.

If you still want to present the application on your front page, I would hide it behind a button where the user can consciously start loading it. You also might want to prevent scrolling during that period - fit all the relevant stuff on the screen, and expand the page downwards when the application is ready. You can also try to pre-load the data in the background, before the user hits the button. To let the heavy data processing not affect the snappiness, run it in a [background process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: +1 *if* it fits the platform. Pinterest's sole purpose is the posts/pins so their homepage is instantly filled with pins, why create a homepage for a platform with one purpose?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Yes, there surely are exceptions to the rule. I wasn't sure whether it's a more traditional webpage that includes a data-heavy "showcase", or more a kind of web application that is primarily visited by registered users.

Answer (score 17):

Your best bet is to render the page formalities and structure in a second or two (ethernet time, cell-data time will vary).  And then, backfill the data as the data comes up.

Imagine if you reboot the starship Enterprise.  There are dozens of displays.  They don't all come up at the same time, they flit on, one at a time, depending on how long they take to do their thing. We consider that normal.  Also, note that the Enterprise bridge does not spasmodically get larger as workstations insert themselves Harry Potter style between other workstations as they start up. The workstations are always there, just the screens (of fixed size) start filling with data. That's the design concept to go for.

Why?

### Your user may not even want that data

It's easy to suffer tunnel vision, or "get-there-itis" as the aviators call it.  You're presuming everyone who lands on the homepage wants the content you've *done all the work on*. Good chance not.

- Some want the "About us" page or "How this business/site works" page - they're not ready to convert, and a big computational load to present your wares is wasted.
- Others want *directions to your site* (think music theatre, they are late to this show, and don't care about ticket availablility for other shows.)
- Others have a question and want to find a way to contact you.
- Etc. etc.  Those users are not unimportant.

It's rude to make them wait.  It's also suicide to delay; because if the big DB crunch never finishes, that means **your site is down**.   **Same** if the big DB crunch takes 7 seconds, but they abandon in 6.

### You're *supposed* to reserve space

This new trend they call "skeleton UIs" where you reserve space for the loading content -- it is not a new thing.  It's a very old thing, and a very mandatory thing.

The web was going quite strong in 1995 when most people had 33.6kbps modems.  You see the `img` tag with its  `height=` and `width=` attributes? They're not for scaling. **The Internet *lived or died* off of those.**  That's what made your site usable within a sufferable amount of time.  That's what put a gray box with a little "image" icon where your content goes. People were used to this, and really appreciated it.  Many set their browser to "don't auto-load images" and clicked to see the ones they wanted.

[image]

*This didn't render (yet)? No matter.  The page could render, and it won't jump.*

Mind you in 1995, it was possible to *fail to* specify `height=` and `width=` parameters, and you would indeed get the sad version of scroll jumping that was possible on a 486 (that's a CPU chip) without a VPU.  This only happened on the cheesiest amateur home-cooked web sites.  *Anyone remember loading a friend's personal travelougue site and having to go get a coffee while his 100 images jerkily loaded?*

So this concept of "Don't cause scroll jumping" **is nothing new**.  Don't *normalize* failure to reserve space for loading content, it's always been a lazy and sloppy way to code.

And yes, that does present design challenges for dynamically loaded content.  In fact, that's how that camel-of-indeterminate-size got its nose back in the tent.  Lazy sites go "We can't know how large this tweet will be" *(I'm gonna guess, less than 140 characters)*... **good design is working this out.**

In the old days, we solved almost any problem like that with an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).  So it's definitely possible.

Comment: Exactly this. You don't know if a specific user wants the content you worry about. Make sure the page is usable and "nice" while its loading. Perhaps even go for "best of both worlds" - a usable page and a loading bar _in the slot where this specific content will go when it's loaded_, for this specific content. As an aside, can you crunch the data periodically on the server so the user web page can download a precrunched version quickly, plus if needed an "(updating in the background" tag?

Comment: "precrunching" seems very doable if this actually shows up on a page before login.

Answer (score 5):

Neither. Since it's the home page, you can assume that users will be going there often. So calculate everything in advance and cache it.

If it's a "live" page that needs to provide up-to-the-minute data every time it is loaded/refreshed, then cache the result from the previous request and use this as the initial page for the next request (if the page has a "last updated" field then include the time that the cached data was originally generated). Then the page can update the data using AJAX after it's loaded. The result is that users see the page load immediately with data that's probably not more than a few minutes out of date, then within a few seconds of the page loading the data's replaced with the up-to-date data. If the user mashes the refresh button, they'll never receive older data because the data from their previous query will be cached and returned the next time.

Also limit the number of AJAX requests that you're doing and perform most of the calculations on the server. This way the client can simply make one AJAX request that returns the entire data a few seconds later rather than overloading the user's computer and network connection with many AJAX requests and a lot of calculations. Plus if you perform the calculations server-side then you can cache the results (see previous paragraphs).

Answer (score 4):

A common solution to this is displaying an incomplete page layout that gradually fills as the information becomes available. Unless the client machine is having to process the data itself, there is no reason why loading data on a background thread should slow down the UI.

Make sure all the buttons experienced users need are accessable from the start to increase productivity.

Comment: the trouble here is that the user might try to interact with some of the data (like I frequently do!)

Comment: There's nothing to stop them doing that. Clicking on the data to enlarge it or whatever should still be possible. A progress bar on the data might be appropriate if it is long enough to warrant it.